# Your goblin routes in season 11?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am trying to farm goblins, but I would like to know the best spots, so I am not randomly running around as a chicken. I searched YT, but it may be outdated...

Comment: No video made in the last 2 years is outdated. They have not updated anything regarding goblin spawns in a very very long time.

Answer (score 3):

Some high value places to frequent include:

- Act I : The Northern Highlands
  Go northwest from the waypoint to the top left corner of the area.
- Act I : Halls of the Ancients level 2
  This used to have a guaranteed goblin in it, but now the rate has been nerfed. Still a good place to clear in search.
- Act II : Halls of Lightning
  If you take the Zoltun Kulle waypoint, run a little further in, and of the 3 portals the one on the right is the Halls of Lightning. There is a good chance of a goblin being in there.
- Act III : Core of Arreat
  This zone has a decent chance of a goblin being there.

I have had the best luck with the Northern Highlands waypoint. All of this is RNG based though, and it is entirely possible that you [Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy#Monte_Carlo_Casino) at one of these places. <strike>For example, I still cannot seem to get the Gibbering Gemstone =/</strike> (Wow, I actually got the Gibbering Gemstone the night after posting this, after at least a hundred previous attempts, apparently posting grievances to Arcade has tangible benefits :D)

Comment: There are new areas added in 2.6, and some were featured in many "2.6 goblin routes" and "season 11 goblin routes". Some videos mention their routes as nerfed, but I didn't watch close enough to give a definite answer.

Comment: Interesting that the new Necro zone was added as a high value target, I wonder how badly it was nerfed. That said, the season 11 routes the author Bluddshed has #1 as Northern Highlights (just as here), and I would have to strongly agree: that is probably the highest chance, smallest window place to look. Waypoint, small check near it in the top left there, next game. Either way, these are just some suggestions from my experience which I have had success with.